# 1. How to call a controller method using url in .jqgrid & 2. Visual Studio Cannot load a project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

### Question 1 :

I am trying implementing `JQgrid` in MVC,
for that  in `.jqgrid` url ,  i have as  `url: '/Personalize/GetAccountHeads',` Where `GetAccountHeads()` is a Method in `PersonalizeController.cs` as.,

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        public JsonResult GetAccountHeads() {                
            List<ACHeadEntry> acHeadEntries = new List<ACHeadEntry>();
            //Some code here to calculate acHeadEntires.
            return Json(acHeadEntries, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

But this method too does not be called. Where I went wrong?

While trying to find that,
I have downloaded the demo project .,

### Question 2 :

http://code.haacked.com/mvc-1.0/JQueryGridDemo.zip And tried to execute it. But I am getting the following error.[image]

The output window shows ..

> C:\Users\developer\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$DIa0.562\GridDemo\GridDemo.csproj
>   : error  : The project file could not be loaded. Could not find a part
>   of the path
>   'C:\Users\developer\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$DIa0.562\GridDemo\GridDemo.csproj'.
>   C:\Users\developer\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$DIa0.562\GridDemo\GridDemo.csproj
>
> C:\Users\developer\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$DIa0.562\DynamicQuery\DynamicQuery.csproj
>   : error  : The project file could not be loaded. Could not find a part
>   of the path
>   'C:\Users\developer\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$DIa0.562\DynamicQuery\DynamicQuery.csproj'.
>   C:\Users\developer\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$DIa0.562\DynamicQuery\DynamicQuery.csproj

Actually many times, It is happening this way. Why I am getting this error.

Also,
I am trying implementing `JQgrid` in MVC,
for that  in `.jqgrid` url ,  i have as  `url: '/Personalize/GetAccountHeads',` Where `GetAccountHeads()` is a Method in `PersonalizeController.cs` as.,

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        public JsonResult GetAccountHeads() {                
            List<ACHeadEntry> acHeadEntries = new List<ACHeadEntry>();
            //Some code here to calculate acHeadEntires.
            return Json(acHeadEntries, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

But this method too does not be called. Where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you use *really old* demo. One can see on the screen that you use Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 which has no support for MVC 1.0. You need first convert MVC 1.0 to MVC 2.0 with [the old tool](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2010/03/10/migrating-asp-net-mvc-1-0-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-2-rtm.aspx) and then convert MVC 2.0 to MVC 3.0 with [another tool](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/59008).

I would recommend you to start better with [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridDemoVS2010.zip) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935) which is also relatively old. It uses MVC 2.0, but using [the second conversion tool](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/59008) MvcAppConverter.exe you can convert it to MVC 3.0. One small step (converting of unneeded `using System.Xml.Serialization;` line in `Models\HaackOverflowEF.Designer.cs`) one have to do manually.

**UPDATED**: I verified that the demo which you referenced (http://code.haacked.com/mvc-1.0/JQueryGridDemo.zip) is already in ASP.NET 2.0 so it's enough to use only one conversion tool (downloadable from [here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/59008))

Comment: Thanks a lot that's working. Any comments on my second question?

Comment: Sorry, Any comments on my first question?

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT: You are welcome! Your first question have no enough details. You posted **no JavaScript code** and your C# code is very common. It could be many reason and I don't want to guess. For example do you used `mtype: "POST"` option to create jqGrid? You need post *both* server and client code for troubleshooting of the problem. Moreover the action should have another parameters. I would forward you to [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935) which demo I referenced in my answer.